# Change action bar to transparent color to work on both Android 2 and Android 3

Tags: android

I get this nice piece of code from http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html, which able to make `ActionBar` GUI on both Android 2 and Android 3 platform.

However, I was wondering, had anyone tried to change the color of `ActionBar`. Note that, the following code will make crash at Android 2, as in Android 2, it doesn't have `ActionBar`.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {           
    ...
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ad_action_bar_gradient_bak));        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) works like charm :)